# nodejs and dynamodb Query, conditional test, and insert

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have a dynamodb check table with:

```
tvariable1, min, max
tvariable2, min, max
tvariable3, min, max
```

My js file then receives data as:

```
variable1, value
variable2, value
variable3, value
```

I need to test each received variable against the table min max, and if it exceeds the min max value, then I need to add each variable as a separate record into a alert table that has: `ID`, `alertRule`, `alertDescr`, `alertValue`

```
switch (true){
    case variable1 > 4:
    case variable1 < 0.5:
    alertRule = "True";
    alertDescr = "variable1 Alert";
    break;
case variable2 < 0.5:
case variable2 > 100:
    alertRule = "True";
    alertDescr = "variable2 Alert";
    break;
case variable3 < 32:
case variable3 > 120:
    alertRule = "True";
    alertDescr = "variable3 Alert";
    break;
}
```

If `variable1` is not in range,  then I need to enter it into alert table, and then test `variable2` and so on.

The switch case above doesn't really work, but it's just an example on how the data is tested.

Comment: what is the hash key attribute of the alert table? Is it ID? If yes, is tvariable1 is the ID value?

Comment: Id is the hash key so the data would be more like: Customer, pressure, temp, volts and if pressure, temp, or volts exceed the range, an alert is made for each instance

Comment: Is variable1 in json equal to Id (i.e. hash key) of the table?